# Internal server Error Using http UrlConnection

Tags: android

I was referred to this
    link
([Upload large file in Android without outofmemory error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9630430/upload-large-file-in-android-without-outofmemory-error))
    for send internal storage file to server After that i got error
    internal server error code 500.In my previous app, it was working perfectly
    Is this client side or my server side problem?

I am using file directory :-

```
 File mydir = context.getDir("mydir",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

Comment: "500 - internal server error" is problem with your server.

Answer (score 0):

This is a error which can be occur due to your mistake.I think you should also post your code with you question which would also help us to understand what you are doing and will easy to amplify your mistake. I am referring you to this link which explains more about server error (error code 500) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22869874/android-retrofit-return-status-500-internal-server-error) and check the timeout you are using in your code .